# @JsonIgnore with an @JsonValue field

Tags: java, json, spring

i've got a problem.

My Json java class:

```
class test {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private titi_type titi;

    public titi_type getTiti() { return titi;}

    public void setTiti(titi_type _titi) { titi = _titi;}

   @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
   @JsonValue
   private List <toto_class_type> toto;

   public List<toto_class_type> getToto(){return toto;}

   public void setToto(final List<toto_class_type> _toto) { toto = _toto;}

}
```

--> titi has @JsonUnwrapped, because i don't want to serialize titi field name
--> toto has @JsonValue because i don't want to serialize toto field name AND @JsonIgnore because i don't want to serialize toto if toto is null.

BUT the result of serialization with toto null = null
I've got a problem with @JsonValue @JsonIgnore mixed

Comment: Put the annotations on the getter instead. Also, I think the @JsonValue annotation is redundant here. You can remove it.

Comment: thanks @marstran but if i remove JsonValue, toto field name "toto" is serialize. AND i don't want this field name. 
i.e, i don't want:
'{
   toto: [
      {....},
      {....}
   ]
}
I want:
'{
    [
      {....},
      {....}
   ]
}'

Comment: But that is invalid JSON. A list inside an object must have a property name.

Comment: But it's a root object, it's not possible?

Comment: You can have the list directly on "root": `[ { ... }, { ... } ]`.